# JQuery scrollTop() not doing anything

Tags: jquery, html

My `.scrollTop()` is just not working. It's used in a function (which do get called - checked with an alert) but nothing happens.

I tried:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
$("html").scrollTop();
$(document).scrollTop();
```

I tried them separately and together, and it just doesn't do anything.

All I need to do is let my page scroll to the top. Any tips and tricks?

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).scrollTop();`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `$("html, body").scrollTop(0);` that is a cross-browser solution to scroll to the vertical position 0 (to the top).

The way you are doing `scrollTop()` does nothing because its a getter that returns the current vertical position.

Answer (score 2):

[scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) *gets* the current scroll top of an element but doesn't set it, try the [jQuery ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo), it has the functionality you need.

Comment: `.scrollTop(pixelPosition)` does in fact set the scrolltop of pages and scrollable elements. You can even animate it.

Answer (score 0):

$("body").scrollTop(); would work just fine.

Comment: you have to pass scrollTop a parameter e.g. `0` else it's just a getter. like Jose said.